# Playout video from iTunes 12 to external monitor

Tags: itunes

I want to be able to play my own videos out of iTunes 12 to an external monitor (HDMI)
and keep the iTunes interface on my laptop screen.

Answer (score 1):

Play the video in fullscreen mode, and active mission control click <kbd>^</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd>, drag the fullscreen playing video to the external display. Another way, you can play the video via Quicktime player